# c# call method from another form to refresh my combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a code here but it didn't work, i want to refresh my combobox from another `form` by calling the method `cmb_lod();`

`Form1` were my combobox created

```
public void cmb_load()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT subjectCode FROM Subjects", con);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            cmbSubjects.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

`Form2` where i want to refresh my combobox after adding value

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmManipulateClass mc = new frmManipulateClass();
    mc.cmb_load();
}
```

Comment: wha'ts going wrong here? any exceptions?

Comment: go through this project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B893d39kVeIvcGhjUG80ZG05OWc/edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the second form, you're creating a NEW instance of the first form and then refresh the combobox on it. This second instance has nothing to do with the first instance. What you need to do is to obtain a reference to the original first form and call the method on it. One way is in the first form:

```
public static frmManipulateClass Current {get; private set;}
public frmManipulateClass()
{
    Current = this;
}
```

and then in the second form:

```
frmManipulateClass.Current.cmb_load();
```

This is only useful if you open just a single instance of the first form.